# How do I back up to iDrive?

Tags: scripts, backup, online-storage

I have purchased a subscription to back up my Linux Mint and Ubuntu systems to i-Drive. I need the iDrive script and instructions for online Linux backup.

Comment: What is iDrive?

Comment: I drive is an online backup subscription. I have used it successfully on Windows for years. https://www.idrive.com/idrive/login/loginForm

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iDrive FAQ](https://www.idrive.com/faq_linux#linuxWeb4) you'll have to contact the [iDrive support](https://www.idrive.com/support) to get the latest script package.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the scripts from idrive.com

See https://www.idrive.com/readme